# Updating visual force page delivered via managed package

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to add some javascript code in a visualforce page that is delivered via managed package is that possible ?

Or is there any work around to access the VF page DOM via JS, Which I am using inside an Iframe. It shows security error since the domain name.

if possible can we use JSONP and PostMessaging ?

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish exactly? There might be a better way to achieve your goals. I also have some ideas that might help, if they're applicable to your situation.

Comment: There are some links present in VF page which is delivered via managed package. I am using those VF page inside VF page iframe. I want to disable those links.